# Values dynamically inserted in stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query which gives me result of my sort
the query looks like:

```
select * from  Question where categoryid like '3%' or categoryid like '%,3'
```

where 3 is a random number and the value can be any depending on the user.

now i have to create a store procedure which take the value dynamically i.e. at the place of 3 we would get an input from user, so how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create procedure GetIt
  @Value varchar(10)
as  
select * 
from Question 
where categoryid like @Value + '%' or 
      categoryid like '%,' + @Value
```